# Ruby (NoMethodError) even when method is declared

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I am getting my hands dirty learning ruby the hard way.
I am stuck at lesson 26. [Here](https://github.com/rituparna89/learn-ruby/blob/master/ex26.rb) is the link to the file. And this is the code snippet where the error lies:

```
five = 10 - 2 + 3 - 6
puts "This should be five: #{five}"

def secret_formula(started)
  jelly_bens = started * 500
  jars = jelly_beans / 1000
  crate = jars / 100
return jelly_beans, jars, crates
end

start_point = 10000
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)
```

this is the error on the console

```
ex26.rb:77:in `<module:Ex25>': undefined method `secret_formula' for     Ex25:Module (NoMethodError)
from ex26.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The link to the gist isn't working.

Comment: Even if the link were working, don't just put a link in the question, Post the code **here**.

Comment: its a big file so posted the link .. lemme get a snippet out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of typos in the variable declarations. First you have `jelly_bens` (missing an "a") instead of `jelly_beans`. Second, you have `crate` (singular) instead of `crates` (plural). Once those are fixed, the code executes properly:

```
five = 10 - 2 + 3 - 6
puts "This should be five: #{five}"

def secret_formula(started)
  jelly_beans = started * 500
  jars = jelly_beans / 1000
  crates = jars / 100
return jelly_beans, jars, crates
end

start_point = 10000
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)
```

Comment: thanks it was really hard for me to spot it... after that i changed almost 15 more errors ...

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of typos in your code, and after you fix that one, more errors will show up. As for it, you typed `ed` instead of `end` on line `30`, and that `end` at the end of the file should be deleted.

Comment: thanks that is actually the exercise to correct someones code

Comment: What i dont understand is if the error is on line 77 ... no method defined when it is actually there

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find this answer anywhere else, so here's how I solved it:

The difference between `def secret_formula(started)` and the other `def`s in this exercise is that they begin with the module name: `def Ex26.break_words(stuff)`

So you can rewrite the problem line here as `def Ex26.secret_formula(started)`

And it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed *self* in "secret_formula" function declaring.
This is my code for this exercise.

```
module Ex25

  # This function will break up words for us.
  def Ex25.break_words(stuff)
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words
  end

  # Sorts the words.
  def Ex25.sort_words(words)
    return words.sort
  end

  # Prints the first word after popping it off.
  def Ex25.print_first_word(words)
    word = words.pop(0)
    puts word
  end

  # Prints the last word after popping it off.
  def Ex25.print_last_word(words)
    word = words.pop()
    puts word
  end

  # Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words.
  def Ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
    words = Ex25.break_words(sentence)
    return Ex25.sort_words(words)
  end

  # Prints the first and last words of the sentence.
  def Ex25.print_first_and_last(sentence)
    words = Ex25.break_words(sentence)
    Ex25.print_first_word(words)
    Ex25.print_last_word(words)
  end

  # Sorts the words then prints the first and last one.
  def Ex25.print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
    words = Ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
    Ex25.print_first_word(words)
    Ex25.print_last_word(words)
  end


puts "Let's practice everything."
puts 'You\'d need to know \'bout escapes with \\ that do \n newlines and \t tabs.'

poem = <<END
\tThe lovely world
with logic so firmly planted
cannot discern \n the needs of love
nor comprehend passion from intuition
and requires an explanation
\n\t\twhere there is none.
END

puts "--------------"
puts poem
puts "--------------"


five = 10 - 2 + 3 - 6
puts "This should be five: #{five}"

def self.secret_formula(started)
  jelly_beans = started * 500
  jars = jelly_beans / 1000
  crates = jars / 100
  return jelly_beans, jars, crates
end


start_point = 10000
beans, jars, crates = Ex25.secret_formula(start_point)

puts "With a starting point of: #{start_point}"
puts "We'd have #{beans} beans, #{jars} jars, and #{crates} crates."

start_point = start_point / 10

sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
words = Ex25.break_words(sentence)
sorted_words = Ex25.sort_words(words)
Ex25.print_first_word(words)
Ex25.print_last_word(words)
Ex25.print_first_word(sorted_words)
Ex25.print_last_word(sorted_words)
sorted_words = Ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
Ex25.print_first_and_last(sentence)
Ex25.print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
end
```